# What is difference between MD5_NUMBER_LOWER64 and MD5_NUMBER_UPPER64

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, 64-bit, md5

From the description, I found that it Calculates the 128-bit MD5 message digest, interprets it as a signed 128-bit big endian number, and returns the upper/lower 64 bits of the number as an unsigned integer.
But what exactly is upper and lower 64 bits.

Comment: This is standard terminology. "Low" bits are the least significant. "High" bits are most significant.

Answer (score 1):

Upper and lower are a way to divide a very long 128-bit number into 2 64-bit numbers.

To see it action:

```sql
select md5_hex('a')
    , to_char(md5_number_upper64('a'), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') upper
    , to_char(md5_number_lower64('a'), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') lower
```

[image]

You can see that `upper` and `lower` just give you two parts of the longer one.